# HBase Table.batch() doesn't respond when running in a reducer

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

I am using CDH5.16.1 version of hbase-client. I have a MapReduce job set up to read some avro files and batch write their content into HBase.

My setup includes a Zookeeper quorum, HBase Thrift server, one HBase master and a bunch of RegionServers.

This batch write worked when using `hbase-client` version 0.98.6-CDH5.3.3. Now, the write path is stuck at Table.batch() function call (i.e. everything worked until this point). I looked at the implementation, it is doing a AsyncFuture callback not sure where it is stuck at.

Just for more information, the batch() signature looks like this per `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table` interface:
  `Object[] batch(final List<? extends Row> actions) throws IOException, InterruptedException;`

I am using Cloudera so I have access to ClouderaManager as well as logs in Zookeeper, Thrift server and HBase RegionServers, but I don't see anything related to this call in the log. Not sure it's because I don't have the proper logging level turned on or there is really nothing received on those servers. Can someone please give some pointers?

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Comment: No. I wrote to an HFile and commit the file to HBase instead.

Comment: so in the end, you wrote the table manually